# ReportDocument.Load(UNC path) doen not work in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, .net-4.8

I have report filename saved in DB.
Eg: folder/file.rpt
I have UNC Path.
`<add key="reportUNCPath" value="\\storage\crystal-reports-file-share\" />` in web.config .

when I use

```
rptDocument.Load(reportUNCPath+"folder/file.rpt") ;
```

report is not loading to CrystalReportViwer.

Comment: Have you checked that the resulting path is valid. You might consider to use something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath to combine the path components.

Comment: Yes. I checked. Manually if I copy and paste it in file explorer, the report exists in that UNC. when I locally copy that rpt file into some of the folder and give that location,then it works.

Comment: And under which user context does the application run? This user can access the network share, too?